# Set keyboard keys only one purpose in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, keyboard, keyboard-events, nsevent

I need a little help here to figure out a way to give a keyboard key only one purpose. I explain : Right now, keys 1-8 on the keyboard have an action associate to them with `NSEvent` and `FirstResponder`. They call a method. The problem is that I need to be able to call this method by pressing 1-8 wherever i am in my app so when the focus is set on a TextFieldI can use those keys. I don't want 1-8 to have their usual purpose. The number pad is going to be where I can use numbers. My question : I wonder if there's a way to do what I want?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Session 145, “Key Event Handling in Cocoa Applications”, from the [WWDC 2010 sessions](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2010/) will tell you everything you need to know.

Comment: Thanks! I'm gonna take a look at it. Hope it's going to help me.